# How to convert lambda from C# to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Lambda expression:

```
public bool IsConnected => (bool?)DeviceInformation.Properties["System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected"] == true;
```

Comment: What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? Stack Overflow isn't a "write my code for me" service. If there's some _specific_ difficulty you have figuring out how to implement this in VB.NET, please be clear about what's giving you trouble.

Comment: I have difficulty to speak English, in "Windows-universal-samples-master" there is program call bluetoothLEClient, so I need small part from the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like a lamdba to me, just a typo with the =>

```
Public IsConnected As Boolean = (CType(DeviceInformation.Properties("System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected"), Nullable(Of Boolean)) = True)
```